# Clique vs genus

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a relation between Clique size $\omega(G)$ and genus $g(G)$ of a graph? That is does $$\omega(G)^c\geq g(G)\geq \omega(G)^{\frac{1}d}$$ hold with constants $c,d\geq1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we can have a graph with a constant clique number but an arbitrarily large graph genus.

The genus of the complete graph on $n \geq 3$ vertices $K_{n}$ is:

$$
\gamma(n) = \left\lceil\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}\right\rceil
$$

We can subdivide the edges of $K_{n}$ to obtain a graph $H$ with clique-number $\omega(H) = 2$ (or anything from $2$ to $n$ as we choose), but of course this still has a $K_{n}$ minor, and hence the same genus as $K_{n}$.

Comment: does same idea work here? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196118/genus-tradeoffs-in-bipartite-graph

Comment: @Turbo, I'm not sure - did you answer that question?

Comment: updated with different questions http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196205/genus-tradeoffs-in-bipartite-graph.